# AjaxToolKit - Extender controls may not be registered before PreRender

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i am trying to the MaskedEditExtender and MaskedEditValidator to work.

im not getting any type of error; however the maskededitextender or validator are completely not working.

the question is exactly similar to:

[ajaxtoolkit maskededitextender not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238887/ajaxtoolkit-maskededitextender-not-working)

ive downloaded a sample of the maskededitor from the asp.net site and running the code exactly as is.

what am i doing wrong?

if you think jquery is better for this please do send me an example!

Comment: What are you doing in PreRender? A little more context would help.

Comment: @chris how do i check this? i dont thing im doing anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must say that it's been long time that I have used the Ajax Toolkit as I started to use more and more jQuery and understand Javascript better, I realized that Ajax Toolkit was creating to much code for really simple things.

**My suggestion goes** to use a jQuery Plugin as you probably are already using jQuery for something else.

**start with this really simple tutorial**:

> http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/how-to-mask-input-with-jquery/

Comment: ajax is just a way to call a method without reloading the entire page and update parts of the page with the result... jQuery is lovely for that! add your question specifying the tag jquery and you will get a lot of help, and in no time you will be a ninja using jQuery for your day to day work!