# Add Page number using Page Property of CSS for each printed pages from asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to print 33 pages from my website but I need to add page number to each printed page using css  I saw alot of solution for that like  [How to print page number using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535269/how-to-print-page-number-using-css)  , [get printed page number of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556777/get-printed-page-number-of-an-element) and [Page numbers with CSS/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109893/page-numbers-with-css-html)
but nothing working for me and it's return an error in  @bottom-right that ' is not a known CSS property name '

my CSS :

```
  <style type="text/css" >
    @media print
    {
      table.break {page-break-after: left}
    .no-print, .no-print *
   {
      display: none; 
     }
     }

  @page {
      @bottom-right {
     content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
    }
   }
   </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment page somehow, look at the examples you have posted already:

```
counter-increment: page;
    counter-reset: page 1;
```

Use pure examples, try if they work, and then try to adapt to your needs.

[Further reading](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#syntax-page-selector)

Where are you getting that error?

Answer (score 0):

To me, the errors you are getting appear to be validation errors.
There are components absent in the CSS 2.1 spec although being supported by all major browsers.

You could try changing your stylesheet validation to CSS3.

If you are using VS, then

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\1033\schemas\CSS\css30.xml
```

is where you could begin.

Comment: This could help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931801/is-it-possible-to-change-css-validation-scheme-in-vs2010

Comment: I installed it but drop down list for the style sheet enabled

Comment: Didn't get what you meant by the drop-down part. 
As the link quotes, " If you can't see it right click on the menu and check Style sheet."

Comment: I found it and I select css3 put still return the same error

Comment: return this error (Validation(CSS 2.1): 'bottom-right' is not a known CSS property name

Comment: Try doing this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246965/css-2-1-errors-not-a-known-property-name

This would surpass the errors as if they were warnings.